# Insert values from one column to another in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

How can I **insert** values from one column to another in the same table?

Say I have:

```
Date    |    Suburb    |    Suburb2
010617       Sydney        Parammatta 
010718       Melbourne     St Kilda
```

I require:

```
Date    |    Suburb    |    Suburb2
010617       Sydney        Parammatta  #copy date and suburb2
010718       Melbourne     St Kilda    #copy date and suburb2
010617       Parammatta                #insert
010718       St Kilda                  #insert
```

In other words, I want to copy 'Suburb2 and 'Date' and insert them as new rows in 'Date' and 'Suburb' respectively.

I know I can achieve this by first copying into temporary column/s and cleaning up later but was wondering if there was a way to do this in one query?

I tried

```
INSERT INTO table (date, suburb) SELECT (date, suburb2);
```

but got a *column "date" does not exist* error.

Comment: You also need to add a FROM clause to that select.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise I needed that if it was in the same table

Comment: Also, form a UNIQUE (or PRIMARY) key on the first two columns and see INSERT IGNORE

Comment: You need to use `From table` in second select statement too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was just my syntax that was off. This worked:

```
INSERT INTO table (date, suburb) SELECT date, suburb2 FROM table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
insert into table(date,suburb) select date,suburb2 from table where suburb2 in ('Parammatta','St Kilda');
```

Note: The `where` condition can be modified accordingly and can be set on `suburb`, `date` or `suburb2`.

Comment: Thanks, just figured it out as well. No need for the where clause in my particular instance but handy to know it's there.

Comment: That's great :) Just accept one of the answers above (it'll be visible against a Green tick then). It'll help others who face similar issues